# How can the Entity type of a PartyId be determined?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2013, phone-call

Using Dynamics CRM 2011. I am learning about ActivityPartys.

Since the PartyId of an ActivityParty is an EntityReference, in order to set the PartyId, you need to know the Entity type.

I am trying to create a new PhoneCall (in a plugin) using the same Recipient as an existing phone call. I can retrieve the recipient's PartyId Guid using LINQ from the ActivityPartySet, but how can I determine the Entity Type, which could be either Account or Contact?

Conversely, is it possible to set the PartyId without knowing the EntityLogicalName?

Update:

Thanks for responding but I either misunderstood you or you misunderstood what I am trying to ascertain. Here's my code right now:

```
 // Get the oldPhoneCall's To ActivityParty list:
                    EntityCollection Recipients = oldPhonecall.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("to");

                    // Use the first one to find the partyId 
                    // Need to do it this way because we don't know if partyId points to an Account or a Contact:
                    Guid activityPartyId = Recipients.Entities[0].Id;
                    var activityParty2 = new Xrm.ActivityParty();

                    context.GetWorkflowHelper().serviceContext.ClearChanges();

                    var queryParty = from ap in context.GetWorkflowHelper().serviceContext.ActivityPartySet
                                     where ap.ActivityPartyId.Equals(activityPartyId)
                                    select new { ap.PartyId, ap.LogicalName };
                    foreach (var party in queryParty)
                    {
                        activityParty2.PartyId = new EntityReference(party.LogicalName, party.PartyId.Id);
                    }
```

I found that in the foreach, party.LogicalName is ActivityParty. This is not the entity type of oldphonecall's recipient, which in my test case is Contact but in other cases is Account.

How do I determine that entity logical name? Where have I gone wrong?

Update2:

In SQL I can see field PartyObjectTypeCode and I know I can map that to an entity type (where 1 = Account, 2= Contact, etc.) but when I query the ActivityPartySet, no such field seems to exist.

Update 3:

Got it -

```
 foreach (var party in queryParty)
                    {
                        activityParty2.PartyId = new EntityReference(party.PartyId.LogicalName, party.PartyId.Id);
                    }
```

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, but if you can please confirm the answer written by dynamicallyCRM, he wrote first and it's correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can I determine the Entity Type, which could be either Account or
>   Contact?

PartyId is of the type [EntityReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference.aspx) where [LogicalName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference.logicalname.aspx) would give you the related entity type.

```
var entityLogicalName = context.EmailSet.FirstOrDefault().To.FirstOrDefault().PartyId.LogicalName
```

> Conversely, is it possible to set the PartyId without knowing the
>   EntityLogicalName?

No, when setting a CRM entity reference both Id and LogicalName are required fields.

Comment: upvoted, sorry I posted my answer 10 seconds after your but the browser didn't notify me

Answer (score 3):

In order to set the PartyId you need to know the LogicalName of the entity.

You didn't post the code, but if you are able to retrieve the Id from a recipient you can retrieve also the LogicalName (they are stored as EntityReference)